# Python Kivy - Change line-height without cutting off text

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to decrease the *line_height* of labels without cutting off parts of the text?

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(
            text='This is a long line\nwith multiple\nline breaks.',
            font_size='100sp',
            line_height=.75
        )


MyApp().run()
```

Or - if not - what else can be done to achieve the same effect?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Label` background is transparent, you can make three separate `Labels` and move them as close together as you want. Of course, too close will result in overlaps. Here is an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass


kv = '''
<MyLabel>:
    font_size: '100sp'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
FloatLayout:
    MyLabel:
        text: 'This is a long line'
        pos: 10, lab2.y + lab2.height - 25  # position this label above the lower one, but down 25 pixels
    MyLabel:
        id: lab2
        text: 'with multiple'
        pos: 10, 0 + lab1.height - 25  # position this label above the lower one, but down 25 pixels
    MyLabel:
        id: lab1
        text: 'line breaks.'
        pos: 10, 0
'''


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


MyApp().run()
```

Note that when you use a single `Label` for multiple lines, the line spacing (`line_height`) minimum value is set to prevent text ascenders and descenders from overlapping. When you run my example code, the ascenders and descenders don't overlap, but that is just luck.

Comment: That would have been my next approach too, but I had hoped to find a solution with just one label.
But thanks nonetheless.